# React Router problem with "Link", Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**My issue is when I try to use "Link" in my Nav.js, I get an Error of**

[image]

[image: Here is my App.js]

[image: Here is my Nav.js]

[image: Here is my Orders.js]

[[image: Here is my Products.js4]

Comment: try putting `<div className="App"><Router></Router></div>` inside your `div` in `App.js`

Comment: return (
    
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <Nav />
          <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/orders" component={Orders} />
          <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
          </Switch>
    </Router>
    </div>
  );

Comment: Did you mean like this? -This still had the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `error` that may occurs will come from your `Home` function component:-

- in `App.js`:- edit your `const` `Home` to this (it should be wrap in `return`):-

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Homepage</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Other than that everything will works just fine tho. Anyhow, you can see it here on this [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4wnpf3?file=src%2FApp.js) to compare it with your current code.

Comment: Thank you for the sandbox. My code matches up... Am I missing something? Like a npm install or something?

Comment: Sometimes it could happen because of the `react`, `react-dom` and `router-router-dom` not up to date. Try see the version that you have now and get it up to the latest one

Comment: Okay... I give up trying to understand why.  In the end, I just copy and paste your code and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I can help

Answer (score 1):

use  `<BrowserRouter>`  in `Nav` component

Comment: Wait.... A new issue has come from that. Now when I click on the link. It changes the URL to /whatever but it does not change the screen. I would need to actually manually refresh the page.

Comment: You need to specify the attribute exact for your indexRoute '/'         <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
 in App.js